# InDesign: change justification on autoflowed text

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, formatting

Is it possible to have two text frames with different justifications, which are linked to allow the text to flow between them?

I'm inheriting an old design someone made using two individual text frames, but the text keeps getting updated and I'd rather have the frames linked, to allow autoflowing from one to the other. I can't find a way to alter the justification of the text frames individually, now that I've linked them.

**Current look:**

[image]

**Desired look:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your design isn't part of a longer document you can use the following solution. It's perhaps a little bit hacky, but it works.

Set up your document as *Facing Pages* and make each page half of the final width. So if your final size for example is 300 × 200 mm you could set it up like this:

[image]

This will give you a document that looks like this:

[image]

Draw your two linked text frames or just draw one textbox with two columns across the spread and add your circular icon in the middle with text wrap applied.

Set the text alignment to *Towards Spine*:

[image]

Now the text will be right-aligned on the left side and left-aligned on the right side automatically:

[image]

You can now simply export a file as *Spreads* or place this InDesign document in another InDesign document if you want.

Comment: Hacky, but it'll work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Text alignment is a paragraph-level property (not a frame property), so for this to work you need to manually add a `Paragraph Return` or (better) a `Frame Break` between those 2 sections. In which case yes, you can then apply individual alignment to both linked sections of the text.

If you keep everything as a single paragraph, with no breaks in between, you only get a single possible alignment.